# UUID Generate with Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel

I was searching for a laravel system that automatically generates UUIDs and found this

```
Str::uuid()->toString();
```

My only concern would be if it generated the same one more than once, does anyone know if it does this? And if so, is there a better option for generating UUIDs only once? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: It's ***very*** unlikely you'll get a collision.

Internally, Laravel uses the [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/) package to generate UUIDs via the `Str` utility class. Ramsey's package follows the [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) spec, which outlines the format and generation specs of UUIDs.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions):

> the number of random version-4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is **2.71 quintillion**
> ...
> This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years.

You're safe trusting that the UUID generated is unique unless you're operating at massive scale.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the help! Good to know that it's that unlikely, I shall use the system laravel has created :)